# e.addEventListener is not a function

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, expo

Screenshot of error:

[image]

I'm running this on Expo and I've been trying to solve this error for about 5 hours now but I can't seem to find a solution. Please send help ;-;
I was uninstalling some unwanted npm modules and tidying my files before this error came about. I have checked at least 5 times now that all import directories are valid. I have also re-initialized this expo-project just to ensure that the package.json file has updated correctly.

The error arises from the contents of , I've tried putting in a test stack navigator and it works.

App.js file

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './src/redux/store';
import AuthStackNavigator from './src/stack/AuthStack';
import LoggedInTabNavigator from './src/stack/LoggedInTab';
import { createStackNavigator, TransitionPresets } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import LoadingScreen from './src/screens/LoadingScreen';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function getHeaderTitle(route) {
    const routeName = route.state ? route.state.routes[route.state.index].name : 'Auth';

    switch (routeName) {
        case 'Home':
            return 'Home';
        case 'Feedback':
            return 'Feedback';
        case 'Profile':
            return 'Profile';
        case 'Arts':
            return 'Arts';
        case 'Quiz':
            return 'Quiz';
        default:
            return routeName;
    }
}

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <NavigationContainer>
                    <Stack.Navigator
                        screenOptions={{
                            gestureEnabled: true,
                            gestureDirection: 'horizontal',
                            ...TransitionPresets.SlideFromRightIOS
                        }}
                        initialRouteName='Loading'
                        headerMode='float'
                        animation='fade'
                    >
                        <Stack.Screen
                            options={() => ({
                                headerShown: false,
                                gestureEnabled: false,
                            })}
                            name='Loading'
                            component={LoadingScreen}
                        />
                        <Stack.Screen
                            options={({ route }) => ({
                                title: getHeaderTitle(route),
                                headerShown: false,
                                headerLeft: null,
                                gestureEnabled: false,
                            })}
                            name='LoggedInTab'
                            component={LoggedInTabNavigator}
                        />
                        {/* <Stack.Screen name='Welcome' component={WelcomeScreen} /> */}
                        <Stack.Screen
                            options={({ route }) => ({
                                title: getHeaderTitle(route),
                                headerShown: false,
                                headerLeft: null,
                                gestureEnabled: false,
                            })}
                            name='Auth'
                            component={AuthStackNavigator}
                        />
                    </Stack.Navigator>
                </NavigationContainer>
            </Provider>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

package.json file

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.6",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.6.3",
    "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs": "^5.1.14",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.2.3",
    "@react-navigation/routers": "^5.4.2",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.2.18",
    "base-64": "^0.1.0",
    "expo": "~37.0.3",
    "expo-constants": "^9.0.0",
    "expo-google-app-auth": "^8.1.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "^8.1.0",
    "expo-permissions": "^8.1.0",
    "firebase": "^7.14.2",
    "react": "~16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "~16.9.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-37.0.1.tar.gz",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.6.0",
    "react-native-modal-selector": "^2.0.1",
    "react-native-paper": "^3.9.0",
    "react-native-picker-select": "^7.0.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.7.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "0.7.3",
    "react-native-screens": "~2.2.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.11.7",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.6",
    "babel-preset-expo": "~8.1.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade your firebase version. You can see this => https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/2991